# How do I get a selection of activities for a single activity using intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I've started learning programming for Android and the tutorial I'm following says that if I add 2 activities to the manifest xml with the same intent I should get a dialog that makes me select one of them, but it doesn't. My Android version is 2.3.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.frisodenijs.usingintent" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".main"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SecondActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_second" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.frisodenijs.SecondActivity" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".ThirdActivity"
            android:label="Third Activity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.frisodenijs.SecondActivity" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Main activity:

```
package com.frisodenijs.usingintent;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.content.Intent;


public class main extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        startActivity(new Intent(main.this, SecondActivity.class));
    }
}
```

Second activity:

```
package com.frisodenijs.usingintent;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;


public class SecondActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
    }

}
```

Main xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".main">


    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="To second button"
        android:onClick="onClick"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Second Activity xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.frisodenijs.usingintent.SecondActivity">

    <TextView
        android:text="This is the second activity"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your onClick with this…

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    startActivity(new Intent("com.frisodenijs.SecondActivity"));
}
```

Comment: It says it cannot find symbol class frisodenijs. Should I make more changes in the code?

Comment: Ohh sorry my mistake, 

use it like this 

startActivity(new Intent(“com.frisodenijs.SecondActivity”));

Comment: Thanks, I know get the pop-up screen now, but I encountered another problem. If I select Second Activity it works, but if I select Third Activity the app crashes. Do you know why that might be?

Comment: It's a class not found exception. ` Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.frisodenijs.usingintent.ThirdActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.frisodenijs.usingintent-2.apk]`

Comment: I fixed by adding a ThirdActivity activity. Weird that the tutorial didn't mention it...